# ¿Para qué sirven las funciones peek, putback, ignore, get y getline en c++?

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando entender estas funciones:

- `peek`
- `putback`
- `ignore`
- `get`
- `getline`

Lo busque en el libro de C++ de Deitel & Deitel pero no le entendi a la informacion que me proporciono.

Comment: Esas son varias preguntas, pero bueno, son funciones para manipular streams. Podrías mencionar qué tema se trata cuando las mencionan, y qué es particularmente lo que no entiendes?

Comment: todas las que comentas estan dentro de std::istream esta es una pagina muy util -> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ despues buscas -> **Unformatted input:** y veras unos link's a las que comentas tiene una breve descripcion y si entras en el tienes mas informacion asi como suelen tener ejemplos espero te ayude. Saludos

Comment: Adicional a los comentarios anteriores, te dejo un [link](http://c.conclase.net/curso/?cap=904c#APD_istream) con información en español sobre istream, Saludos!

Comment: Bueno lo que no entiendo es especificamente para que sirve la fucnion peek y la putback son las que mas me confunden pero si pueden explicarmelas todas mejor

Answer (score 3):

Es una pregunta muy extraña para una página como esta dado que la información que buscas es consultable directamente en páginas de documentación y manuales, con una sencilla búsqueda podrías encontrar toda la información que buscas, algunas personas incluso podrían responderte con un [RTFM!](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM).

Sin embargo, pese a lo que he mencionado en el parágrafo anterior, hay motivos de peso para hacer la pregunta que has hecho ya que la documentación sobre programación en Español es realmente escasa e incompleta, así que entiendo perfectamente la motivación tras tu pregunta.

[Angel Angel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/24/angel-angel) ha sugerido usar [cplusplus](http://en.cppreference.com/w/), la cuál es una página creada y mantenida por un Español (y pese a ello, no dispone de versión en Español). En algunos círculos esta página tiene mala fama, al parecer tiene *malos* ejemplos o documentación no actualizada... aunque si te soy sincero no he encontrado nada parecido.

Mi elección personal es [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) que puede ser consultada en Español, tan sólo cambia el inicio de la dirección web de `en` a `es` y se realizará una traducción del contenido:

- Documentación sobre istream en Inglés: [`http://`**`en`**`.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream).
- Documentación sobre istream en Español: [`http://`**`es`**`.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream).

Pero mejor usa este truco con moderación ya que las traducciones suelen ser *algo confusas* (por no usar un término despectivo).

---

En cuanto a tu pregunta.

`peek` Significa "echar un vistazo" en Inglés, la acción que realiza sobre el *stream* es consultar el siguiente elemento **sin extraerlo**. Puede ser útil cuando deban realizarse acciones determinadas relacionadas con el siguiente elemento como (por ejemplo) mostrar el contenido si el siguiente es un retorno de carro (`'\n'`).

`putback` Significa "poner atrás" en Inglés, y lo que hace es escribir el elemento facilitado en el punto en que el puntero de lectura se encuentra, de manera que el siguiente elemento leído sería precisamente el que acabas de poner.

`ignore` Significa "ignorar" en Inglés, tal y como su nombre indica ignora la cantidad de elementos indicada desde el puntero de lectura y avanza dicho puntero, se le puede facilitar también un separador el cuál finalizaría también el proceso de ignorado, el puntero de lectura se colocaría tras este separador. Es decir ignora hasta `X` elementos o hasta que encuentra el separador.

`get` Significa "obtener" en Inglés, se usa para extraer uno o más elementos del stream (dependiendo de la sobrecarga usada), dispone de sobrecargas en que le facilitas un separador el cuál se usará para finalizar la extracción.

`getline` Significa "obtener línea" en Inglés, funciona como `get` pero extrae líneas completas, es decir: extraerá elementos del stream hasta que encuentre un final de línea (generalmente `'\n'`) y finalizará la extracción; el final de línea no se incluye en la extracción. El comportamiento puede ser configurado indicando qué elemento debe ser considerado final de línea.