# ¿Para qué sirve la función cin.get en c++?

Tags: c++

Buenas tardes, estoy iniciando en la programación con C++ y me he topado varias veces con esta función: `cin.get`

¿Podrían decirme el uso o la función que se le da a la misma?

Comment: Recientemente preguntaron [algo parecido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8019/2742).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### C++ función cin.get()

> **cin.get()** es una función que lee un carácter que se introduce desde el
> teclado, el cual podemos almacenar en una variable.

`cin.get()` (librería iostream) es similar a [`getchar()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) (librería stdio)

Este es un ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char texto;
texto = cin.get();
cout << "El primer caracter introducido es: " << texto << endl ;    
return 0;
}
```

al escribir un texto, solo el primer caracter es almacenado en la variable `texto`, por medio del método `cin.get()`, esta seria la salida al escribir la palabra "Daniel":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]